# extracting the local maxima (coordinates) from a 2d likelihood matrix (numpy array) efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, object-detection, tracking

I'm trying to extract the coordinates of the local maxima from a numpy 2D matrix. the values are numbers between 0 and 1 representing a likelihood that an object is in that location.

I've tried threshold-ing the matrix and extracting the argmax and saving the coordinates and changing it's value to 0 and looping until the threshold encountered.

```
 detections = []
 while True:
    maxloc = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(scmap),
                              scmap.shape)
    if scmap[maxloc] > 0.9:
        # other code ..
        detections.append(maxloc)
        scmap[maxloc] = 0
# after that, what i did is calculating the euclidean distance 
# between each pair and excluded the ones that does not meet the  
# threshold
```

I am not satisfied with this, and i think there is more efficient elegant ways to extract the local maxima. thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Locating local maxima is a built-in feature of scikit-image which locates values that are maximal within some predefined distance.

```py
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
coordinates = peak_local_max(scmax, min_distance=5)
```

I'm not sure how this is actually implemented but one implementation method is perform non-maximal suppression (i.e. Iterate through each value in the matrix and compare with all values within a radius. If the value is not maximal in that window then set it to some predefined value like zero or -inf). Then take the coordinates of all non-suppressed values (possibly above some threshold) as the collection of local maxima.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract coordinates of a Numby Matrix, of all of the values that meets a certain threshold, you can simply compare the threshold to the entire matrix.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([
    [0, 0.5, 0.95],
    [0, 0.95, 0.5],
    [0.95, 0.5, 0]
])
thresholded_coordinates = np.argwhere(data > 0.9)

# array([[0, 2], [1,1], [2, 0]])
```

The output of the thresholded_coordinates is a pairwise collection of coordinates. (0,2) indicates it is the third value in the first row (0-indexed). The output is indicated on the comment on the last line.